# How to search a column using a wildcard keyword, where the columns values have more than one word

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, wildcard

I have created a search bar for my website, the user may search a specific category, man or woman etc by a selecting this option from a drop down menu, then entering in a keyword which searches against the selection. The product names all have multiple words, e.g Ultracool Aero Vest or Cyclone Jacket etc...

This is my query, the  variable $term is the passed keyword:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE CATALOGUEID = (SELECT CATALOGUEID FROM PRODUCT_CATALOGUE WHERE PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%" . $term . "%') AND category1 = 1  ";
```

Now this works, but I need to enter the entire product name for it to find anything, I am racking my brains trying to figure out how to allow a user to search by entering only one word such as, jacket or vest. I have been researching this and experimenting with regular expressions and wildcards, but I have not been successful, I am not sure if this is even possible. The W3 schools site does show examples of how to search parts of some words, but not multiple words.Any advice is appreciated.

I am editing my question, as I have to inform everyone that I am using SQL server 2008 and cannot use any MySQL syntax. I keep forgetting that I need to distinguish this when posting questions regarding SQL. Apologies.

Comment: You're going to want to do something about case, I'd imagine; your examples don't match your given search strings.  And **please** tell me you're sanitizing your input - Otherwise, you'll get hit with SQL injection.

Comment: Please, for the love of Zeus, use parameterized queries instead of slapping user-supplied strings directly into your SQL statements.

Comment: I promise that I will be sanitising all of my queries using parameters, once I have finished the queries and they are working. I start simple as I feel it is easier to build up queries where I am entering unknown territories such as in my question :)

I am slowly realising that W3 schools is not a good resource.

Thanks for all your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out how to do this eventually, all along my problem was using = instead of IN, here is the query now working perfectly, note I am no longer concatenating the keyword wildcard:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE CATALOGUEID IN (SELECT CATALOGUEID FROM PRODUCT_CATALOGUE WHERE PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%?%') AND category1 = 1  ";
```

Thanks for all your input and help on this.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take is:

- use `explode` to split the string up
- Loop through the resulting array to create a separate where clause for each element in the array, `WHERE PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%" . $term[n] . "%') OR` ... etc

It isn't very sophisticated in terms of matching but should get you every word in a multi-word search.

Comment: You don't (and in fact can't) need multiple `WHERE` clauses.  However, dynamically adding `OR` conditions is a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it was implied that you only use one `WHERE` clause :)

Comment: Well, you never know what some people will believe or try - like the people who think SQL has inherent ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of that, but I think your `like` clause works fine. 
Try only this request in you mysql client :

```
SELECT CATALOGUEID FROM PRODUCT_CATALOGUE WHERE PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%" . $term . "%'
```

(you have to use the same keyword as the one you've used before)
Do you have more than one result? If so, maybe the problem is that you should use a join instead of a subquery, or a IN instead of the "=".

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.* FROM PRODUCTS JOIN PRODUCT_CATALOGUE using(CATALOGID) where PRODUCT_CATALOGUE.name like "%'.mysql_real_escape_string($term).'%";
```

(yeah, btw, add a "`mysql_real_escape_string`" for security sake)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately I am using SQL server and cannot use any MySQL syntax, I have updated my question to point this fact out, is there an SQLSRV alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know sqlserver, but I guess you can do a join :)